# AWS Elastic Beanstalk commands return no output

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebcli

I am very new to the Amazon Web Services and have been trying a learn-by-doing approach with them.

In summary I was trying to set up Git with the elastic beanstalk command line interface for my web-app. However, I wanted to use my SSH key-pair to authenticate (aws-access-id, secret) and in my naivety and ignorance, I just supplied this information (the SSH key files) and now I can't get it to work. More specifically stated below.

I have my project directory with Git set up so that it works. I then open the git bash window MINGW64 (I am on Windows 10) and attempt to set up eb.

```
$ eb init
```

It then tells me that my credentials are not set up and asks me for aws-access-id and the secret. I had just set up the SSH key-pair and try to enter these files; what's the harm in trying? EB failure, it turns out. Now, the instances seem to run fine still, looking at their status on the AWS console website. However, whatever I type into the bash:

```
$ eb init

$ eb status

$ eb deploy

$
```

There is no output. Not even an error. It just silently returns to awaiting a new command from me.

When using the --debug option with these commands, a long list of operations is returned, ending with

```
botocore.parsers.ResponseParserError: Unable to parse response (no element found: line 1, column 0), invalid XML received:
b''
```

I thought I would be able to log out or something the like, so that I could enter proper credentials which I messed up from the beginning. I restarted the web-app from the AWS webpage interface and restarted my PC. No success.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
I also tried reinstalling awscli and awsebcli:

```
pip uninstall awsebcli
pip uninstall awscli
pip install awscli
pip install awsebcli --upgrade --user
```

Problem persists, but now there is one output (previously seen only upon --debug option):

```
$ eb init
ERROR: ResponseParserError - Unable to parse response (no element found: line 1, column 0), invalid XML received:
b''

$
```

Comment: Can you pass the `--debugboto` flag to `eb <command>` to see what the  response that `botocore` is receiving that appears to be erroneous looks like? Also, take a look at your ~/.aws/credentials and ~/.aws/config files to see if your SSH key has replaced the AWS ID/Secret Key.

Comment: @progfan Write an answer and I can accept it. It was the config file that I modified and set to the proper values. After that, it worked flawlessly. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, glad you found the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have replaced your AWS credentials in `~/.aws/credentials` and/or `~/.aws/config` file(s) with your SSH key. You could manually replace these or execute `aws configure` if you have the AWS CLI installed.